# why all commands disappear when I run this function placed in my .zprofile

Tags: zsh

I have this function in my .zprofile, in my zsh I'm sourcing this file

```
function fd {
    path=$(find ~/Documents ~/Documents/**/ -mindepth -maxdepth -type d | fzf)
    
    if [ -z $path ]; then
        return
    fi
    
    cd $path
}
```

then I can run fd as anyother command in my terminal, but before that I cannot run any other command like: ls,cd,etc...

```
~ $ fd
```

the fd command place me in the directory I selected

```
nodejs $ ls
```

once place in the new directory I cannot use anyother command

Comment: In a POSIX-compliant shell, only upper-case variable names like `PATH` are special, but zsh gladly breaks that standard, making `path` special too. Pick a different variable name. (Relevant standard subset at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- read it keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a single namespace, as setting a shell variable having a given name controls the value of any environment variable with that same name).

Comment: In `zsh`, the variable `path` has special meaning. It is an array tied to variable `PATH`. When you change `path`, you also change `PATH`. You can try it out by doing a `(path=(foo bar); echo $PATH)`.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell):

> In cases where there are two parameters with an upper- and lowercase form of the same name, such as `path` and `PATH`, the lowercase form is an array and the uppercase form is a scalar with the elements of the array joined together by colons. These are similar to tied parameters created via `typeset -T`. The normal use for the colon-separated form is for exporting to the environment, while the array form is easier to manipulate within the shell. Note that unsetting either of the pair will unset the other; they retain their special properties when recreated, and recreating one of the pair will recreate the other.

So by assigning a scalar value to the array variable `path`, you're also clobbering `PATH`, meaning zsh won't find any programs to run unless you give a path, not just a name. Use a different name for your variable.